Hibernate: Mapping without Foreign Key Constraint
I have an eventchangelog table and a user table, and I’m trying to map a User object to an eventChangeLog entry based on a username column. The user table has username as a unique field, but for business reasons, I can’t add a foreign key constraint between eventchangelog.createdby and user.username.
Problem
I only want to store the username in eventchangelog but would like Hibernate to load the entire User object (first name, surname, username, etc.) when fetching an EventChangeLog entry. However, I’m having trouble mapping the User to my EventChangeLog class unless I use a constructor in my HQL query.
Here’s what I’m working with:
EventChangeLog Class
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class EventChangeLog {
    private long id;
    private Event event;
    private String createdByUsername;
    private User createdBy;
    
    // Constructor initializes all fields except `id`
}

EventChangeLog Hibernate Mapping
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.event.EventChangeLog" table="eventchangelog">
        <id name="id" column="eventchangelogid">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence_name">eventchangelog_sequence</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="event" class="org.event.Event"
                     column="eventid" foreign-key="fk_eventchangelog_eventid" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="createdByUsername" column="createdby" type="string"/>
        <many-to-one name="createdBy" class="org.event.User" insert="false" update="false" property-ref="username">
            <column name="createdby"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

User Class
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String surname;
    private String firstName;
}

User Hibernate Mapping
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.event.User" lazy="false" table="userinfo">
        <property name="username" column="username" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
        <property name="surname" not-null="false" length="160"/>
        <property name="firstName" not-null="false" length="160"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Queries Attempted
When I use this HQL query with a constructor, it maps everything correctly:

String hql = """
    select new org.event.EventChangeLog(
        ecl.event,
        ecl.createdByUsername,
        ecl.createdBy
    )
    from EventChangeLog ecl
    join ecl.event e
    left join ecl.createdBy
    where e.uid = :eventUid
""";

However, if I use the following query, which should map directly to EventChangeLog, the User object (createdBy) is not mapped:
String hql = """
    select ecl
    from EventChangeLog ecl
    join ecl.event e
    left join ecl.createdBy
    where e.uid = :eventUid
""";

Things I’ve Tried

Foreign Key Constraint: Adding a foreign key didn’t work due to business constraints.
Primary Key Mapping: Mapping by user.id didn’t work either.
Eager vs Lazy Fetching: Both approaches didn’t change the result.
Used CriteriaQuery instead of HQL: Same outcome; User is not fetched.
Hibernate Logs: The join query seems correct and looks exactly the same in both cases, so I suspect the issue is in the mapping configuration.

How can I configure Hibernate to map the User object to EventChangeLog using the username column without using a constructor in my HQL query?

In your HQL query, rather than relying on Hibernate to automatically map the User object, you can use a custom result transformer to manually set the User object on the EventChangeLog. This approach allows you to retrieve the fields you need and map them (by setting a ResultTransformer)  even without a foreign key constraint.
Here’s an example of how you might do this:
Query query = session.createQuery("""
    select ecl.id, ecl.event, ecl.createdByUsername, u
    from EventChangeLog ecl
    join ecl.event e
    left join User u on ecl.createdByUsername = u.username
    where e.uid = :eventUid
""");

query.setParameter("eventUid", eventUid);
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

List<EventChangeLog> results = query.list();

If you want to change the selected data you can have a matching DTO class and call instead of having  :
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

you can set it like this :
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(EventChangeLogDTO.class));


This approach explicitly fetches EventChangeLog fields and the associated User, then manually sets the User object on EventChangeLog.
